# Undelete a particular retracted answer that provides context

Tags: discussion, deleted-answers

At [Is the bilinear resampling technique appropriate for the projection of ASTER data?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/113666/is-the-bilinear-resampling-technique-appropriate-for-the-projection-of-aster-dat) @Aaron retracted [his answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/113668/108) and now only those with sufficient repuation can read it.

From reading this and related threads I concur with the retraction, however I think the answer still holds valuable information in tracking the path of the conversation and for those wishing to follow the research. (Particularly the name of the academic Jensen and associated papers. The comments are also informative.)

In my opinion in would be better to undelete the post and preface it with something like *"here for reference, this is no longer a position [Aaron] holds".*

Undeleting the post would then allow cross referencing from other places like this [@RachelM answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/213006/108) for those wishing to get more background information on the debate.

Comment: In a focused Q&A site is there any benefit to trying to track the path of a conversation?

Answer (score 2):

I deleted the post originally because I was not satisfied with the references that I supplied. I agree with PolyGeo in that it would be counterproductive to undelete the post as we are striving to cultivate a focused Q & A site. I think the best solution would be suggesting any edits to the person who's answer was accepted.

Comment: After thinking on it some more, my aim was not so much to track the conversation development but in attempting to unfold the question: "Why do some RS folks with a significant knowledge abd track record insist that Nearest Neighbour is in fact better than Bilinear, Cubic and other resampling methods?" and your post was the only one I found in GIS Stack that had a reference one could try and track down.  So actually this is better asked as it's own Q.

Answer (score 0):

If it had happened to me, I would not want not having the option to delete an own answer which I no longer supported just to be an example to others on 'how to not do it' (or something like that). It would be uncomfortable.

As a workaround, one (who sees the deleted answer) can pick up the relevant parts of the deleted answer and make his/her own. Perhaps writing with a different angle on the subject: *"If going this way, consider these caveats, those consequences, etc."*